# What result codes can be returned from BillingClient.launchBillingFlow()?

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

I'm using using Google's Billing Library 4. The documentation for `BillingClient.launchBillingFlow` says:

> Initiates the billing flow for an in-app purchase or subscription.
>
> It will show the Google Play purchase screen. The result will be delivered via the `PurchasesUpdatedListener` interface implementation set by `BillingClient.Builder.setListener(PurchasesUpdatedListener)`.

The `PurchasesUpdatedListener` is passed a `BillingResult` object that contains a response code. However, the `launchBillingFlow` method also returns a `BillingResult` object. My question is, what response codes do I need to deal with in each place?

The documentation is, shall we say, less than clear, and also seems wrong. For `launchBillingFlow`, it says that the method returns a `BillingResult` with a code of `BillingResponseCode.BILLING_CANCELED` if the user cancels the purchase flow. However, my experiments show that code is actually delivered in a call to `PurchasesUpdatedListener.onPurchasesUpdated`.

Unfortunately, the source code for `BillingClient` isn't available, but I did decompile the library module. As far as I can tell, the call to `launchBillingFlow` can return the following result codes:

- `OK` - when the flow successfully starts (and the user is shown Google's purchase screen).
- `SERVICE_DISCONNECTED` - when the `BillingClient` isn't currently connected to Google Play on the device.
- `SERVICE_TIMEOUT` - if the connection breaks during the attempt to launch the flow. (I think I read somewhere that this can happen if Google Play is being updated in the background.)
- `FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED` - under various conditions where the `BillingFlowParams` don't match the current configuration of the `BillingClient` object.

There also seems to be a place in the decompiled code where certain error responses from the Google Play billing service are captured and returned here. Does anyone know what other response codes can be returned from a call to `launchBillingFlow`?

Comment: Actually you can ignore result return when you call `launchBillingFlow`, the result OK here means the app starting purchase follow successfully. You should focus on the result pass to `onPurchasesUpdated` method. this is final result when user purchased or cancelled or already owner of item...

Comment: @CôngHải - It doesn't seem right to simply ignore it. It's clear from what I can decipher from the decompiled code that the purchase flow can fail to start, and my code should be aware of when that happens and react differently based on the reason for the failure.

Comment: The bizarre thing is that launchBillingFlow is not modal. Therefore the CANCELLED return value doesn't make sense. The user may see the dialog and press the back button, but the return from launchBillingFlow() has already happened before that. I'm struggling to understand how to incorporate this new version of the Billing Library into my app - as the dialog is not modal you cannot know if the user pressed back button or continued. You cannot perform UI changes from onPurchasesUpdated (and would not know if it was cancelled either).

Comment: Ignore the last part of what I said. The USER_CANCELED gets sent through to onPurchasesUpdated() and you can handle UI from there.

Comment: @cbn - Yes, that's the point of my question. What result codes need to be handled when `launchBillingFlow` returns and what codes need to be handled in `onPurchasesUpdated()`? There's obviously some overlap, but there's also obviously some codes that are unique to each context. The documentation just lists all possible return codes, without distinguishing which should be handled where.

Comment: Hey TedHopp, @cbn! Did you guys ever found the answer to this? We're also updating to v4 now and double-checking every single call and callback. I find it very, very odd. If anything, I guess we'll handle any unsuccessful error code as a "generic" error, notify the user and hit some analytics. It'd be great if any Google engineers could chime in!

Comment: @necavit - Nope. We're just making assumptions about what codes to expect where and treating anything that violates the assumptions as an unknown error.

Comment: Thanks TedHopp! :) We'll carry on with the same strategy, then. If I ever manage to get feedback from the Google team on this subject, I'll definitely share it here :D

Comment: @necavit -- !

Comment: I'm back here again after all this time. I've been Googling for an answer and found this again. IAB is a bit ridiculous. The immediate result may not even be worth dealing with. For instance, if there is no network (eg: airplane mode) then IAB will return an immediate result of network error - BUT it will also internally pop up a dialogue to announce this. So what do you do? If your app pops up a dialogue it's a duplicate. Some errors may be handled internally and some not. Still no documentation on this.

Comment: Just an additional comment on this. On my devices (both old and new Android) if the device is in landscape and is in airplane mode then the immediate return is OK and, bizarrely (stupidly!) the listener is *never* called! What kind of weirdness is this??? This is with IAB version 6.0. You'd think they'd have got this sorted out by now.

Answer (score 2):

As per the my experience you can handle the result like mentioned below example :-

```
 this.mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {
      if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : list) {

          if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            addPurchaseDetails(purchase);
            handlePurchase(purchase);

          }
        }
      } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        Log.v("purchase", billingResult.getDebugMessage());
      }
```

Means you have to check :- billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null

And get the Purchase from the list and handle the purchase as per your need.

```
    for (Purchase purchase : list) {
       }

Also find the errors below :-  

public @interface BillingResponseCode {
        int SERVICE_TIMEOUT = -3;
        int FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED = -2;
        int SERVICE_DISCONNECTED = -1;
        int OK = 0;
        int USER_CANCELED = 1;
        int SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
        int BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3;
        int ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4;
        int DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5;
        int ERROR = 6;
        int ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED = 7;
        int ITEM_NOT_OWNED = 8;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, of course I can handle all errors in a catch-all `else` branch. However, my question was about what errors to expect in each situation (launching the billing flow or processing the result of a billing flow).

Comment: You can check the error like (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.XXX). XXX will be public @interface BillingResponseCode {
        int SERVICE_TIMEOUT = -3;
        int FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED = -2;
        int SERVICE_DISCONNECTED = -1;
        int OK = 0;
        int USER_CANCELED = 1;
        int SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
        int BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3;
        int ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4;
        int DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5;
        int ERROR = 6;
        int ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED = 7;
        int ITEM_NOT_OWNED = 8;
    }

Comment: Please read my question again. I'm aware of all the possible values. However, not all values can be returned in all places. For instance, `USER_CANCELED` logically cannot be returned from `launchBillingFlow()` because if that call fails, the user has not even seen the billing screen to have the opportunity to cancel. The question is not what are the possible error codes; rather it is, which errors might be returned from which API calls?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your good question. As far as I researched, the values ​​listed below are available.

```
BillingClient.BillingResponseCode // all codes
```

> *int* **BILLING_UNAVAILABLE** Billing API version is not supported for the
> type requested.
>
> *int* **DEVELOPER_ERROR** Invalid arguments provided to the API.
>
> *int* **ERROR** Fatal error during the API action.
>
> *int* **FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED** Requested feature is not supported by Play
> Store on the current device.
>
> *int* **ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED** Failure to purchase since item is already
> owned.
>
> *int* **ITEM_NOT_OWNED** Failure to consume since item is not owned.
>
> *int* **ITEM_UNAVAILABLE** Requested product is not available for purchase.
>
> *int* **OK** Success.
>
> *int* **SERVICE_DISCONNECTED** Play Store service is not connected now -
> potentially transient state.
>
> *int* **SERVICE_TIMEOUT** The request has reached the maximum timeout before
> Google Play responds.
>
> *int* **SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE** Network connection is down.
>
> *int* **USER_CANCELED** User pressed back or canceled a dialog.

```
launchBillingFlow // return values for
```

> The result of the launch billing flow operation.
> **BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED**
> if the user already owns the item being purchased,
> **BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE**
> if the item is not available to be purchased, and
> **BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED**
> if the user dismissed the purchase flow.

Update Answer

> what are the possible return values when the call to
> launchBillingFlow() fails

- ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED
- ITEM_UNAVAILABLE
- USER_CANCELED

> what are the possible values when onPurchasesUpdated() is called (at
> the completion of the flow).

- OK
- ITEM_UNAVAILABLE
- ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED
- USER_CANCELED
- **ERROR** launchBillingFlow Error

Comment: You've just listed all the possible values for `BillingResponseCode`. However, that wasn't my question. The issue is: what are the possible return values when the call to `launchBillingFlow()` fails and what are the possible values when `onPurchasesUpdated()` is called (at the completion of the flow). For instance, it is logically impossible for `USER_CANCELED` to be returned from `launchBillingFlow()` because if that call fails, the user has not even been presented with the opportunity to cancel the purchase.

Comment: I updated my answer. I suggest you specifically check the ERROR status, as the callback will be called in any case.

Comment: Please explain the source for your modified answer, which I think cannot be right. For instance, how could `USER_CANCELED` possibly be returned from `launchBillingFlow()`? If the call fails, then the billing flow has not been presented to the user and the user has had no opportunity to cancel.